# how to handle error clean up separately for parallel jobs in oozie

Tags: parallel-processing, oozie

I have to run a set of parallel jobs in oozie which i am able to run using the fork option in oozie.
Now the problem which i am facing is if one job fails the rest of the jobs also fail because i am calling the kill control node on error for every single job.
I ve searched on the web a lot but i couldnt find how to handle the error clean up separately for every single job.

Any help would be appreciated.

My workflow.xml is as follows:

```
<workflow-app name="WorkFlowForSshAction" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="copyfroms3tohdfs"/>
<action name="copyfroms3tohdfs">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${s3tohdfsscript}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="createhivetables"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>


<action name="createhivetables">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${createhivetablesscript}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="gold__pos_denorm_trn_itm_offr"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="gold__pos_denorm_trn_itm_offr">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${denormalizationscript}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="forknode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<fork name="forknode">
        <path start="gold__dypt_pos_trn_offr"/>
        <path start="gold__hr_pos_trn_offr"/>
                <path start="approach3"/>
                <path start="aproach11"/>
                <path start="aproach12"/>
                <path start="aproach13"/>
                <path start="aproach14"/>
                <path start="aproach15"/>
                <path start="aproach16"/>
                <path start="aproach17"/>

</fork>
<action name="gold__dypt_pos_trn_offr">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${daypartscript}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="gold__hr_pos_trn_offr">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${hourscript}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="approach3">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${approach3script}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="aproach11">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${approach11script}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="aproach12">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${approach12script}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="aproach13">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${approach13script}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="aproach14">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${approach14script}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="aproach15">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${approach15script}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="aproach16">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${approach16script}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<action name="aproach17">
<ssh xmlns="uri:oozie:ssh-action:0.1">
<host>${CMNodeLogin}</host>
<command>${approach17script}</command>
<capture-output/>
</ssh>
<ok to="joinnode"/>
<error to="killAction"/>
</action>
<join name="joinnode" to="end"/>
<kill name="killAction">
<message>"Killed job due to error"</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new node(mostly java) which will perform the clean up activities for you. Also route all the "error to" actions to this new node. You will be able to identify the node which actually caused the error using EL function - **${wf:lastErrorNode()}**. Pass this as an argument to cleanup handling node, so that inside java you can do whatever logic you wish to have for clean up(use java hdfs API).

The new node would be like:

```
<action name="myCleanUpAction">
<java>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <main-class>com.foo.CleanUpMain</main-class>
        <arg>${wf:lastErrorNode()}</arg>
        <arg>any useful argument1</arg>
        <arg>any useful argument2</arg>
    </java>
    <ok to="fail"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```